# Aligning inner panel in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]Folks,

I am newbie to bootstrap and not able to align inner panel with outer panel.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="panel panel-default bs-example">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Outer</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="templateForm" class="form-horizontal bs-example" style="min-height: 320px;">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputName" placeholder="Display Name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="padding:0px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Description</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

1) I want inner panel(Description) to start from the border of outer panel. (Attached dark line padding should be removed in the image)

2) I want some kind of an option where user can collapse/minimize the outer panel and by default only panel title should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

So change `padding:15px` to `padding:15px 0` in `.panel-body` (to remove left padding) and add `padding-left` to `.form-group`

Here:

```
.panel-body {
    padding:15px 0;  
}

.form-group {
  padding-left:15px;
}
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/UV5wsddAoW

Answer (score 0):

If you really want this you can add a class to the inner panel, for example `inner-panel`, and add a negative margin on it. By default Bootstrap uses 15px of padding on a `panel-body` so you need to offset that.

```
.inner-panel {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

For collapsing the inner panel you need to use Bootstrap's JavaScript components, specifically http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse.

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#inner-panel-body">
```

I've added a `data-toggle="collapse"` and `href="#inner-panel-body"` to the `panel-heading` of the inner panel. This tells Bootstrap that a click on the header should expand the element selected by the css selector `#inner-panel-body`. I also added some css to always show a *hand* icon when hovering the header. Another option would be to use an `<a>` tag around the description of the header.

```
<div class="panel-body collapse" id="inner-panel-body"></div>
```

The `panel-body` gets the class `collapse` making the panel be collapsed by default and the id `inner-panel-body`, to be used by the `href` on the `panel-heading`

It might also be an idea to see if you can use more of Bootstrap's grid classes to add a container, row and responsive columns around your content. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```css
.inner-panel {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.inner-panel .panel-heading {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default bs-example">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Outer</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name="templateForm" class="form-horizontal bs-example" style="min-height: 320px;">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label for="inputName" class="control-label">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputName" placeholder="Display Name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-panel panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" href="#inner-panel-body">
          <h3 class="panel-title">
            Description
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body collapse" id="inner-panel-body"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks this is what I was looking for. I would prefer some other control when panel is collapsed. (As of now it is giving some hand icon) Is it possible to give some sort of icon where we can give symbol like ( > ) like EXTJS panels.